# JSF2.0 PostConstructApplicationEvent managed bean is null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

We have JSF2.0 in Tomcat6.0 , need to initialize a ApplicationScope Bean while web server is started.
I tried using the PostConstructApplicationEvent processEvent method to initialize the Bean , but the managed bean from faces-config.xml is returning null.

Is there any other better way to instantiate the bean after startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **any** `faces-config.xml` declarations related to the bean (they will otherwise override the JSF 2.0 annotations) and then annotate the bean with [`@ManagedBean(eager=true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {
    // ...
}
```

This way the bean will always be instantiated on JSF webapp startup, without the need to view any page. You can then do the initialization job in the constructor and/or `@PostConstruct` of the bean.

Comment: I have it only on @ManagedBean(eager=true) ,but when i access it inside PostConstructAPplicationEvent ,it is null.  Does it not initialized when PostConstruct is called?

Comment: when i come inside the PostConstruct it looks like appMap doesn't have the Bean with applicationsscope